# Get most recently added item from an adapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.2

Our app is adapted from the Openkeychain app on github. In our app we have a Main activity which contains a fragment which further contains a listview populated by a cursor adapter, displaying pgp keys imported by the user. When you tap on a listview item(key), user is taken to another activity which is populated depending on the item selected, showing further details of the key and fingerprint associated with it. The app also has another activity where you can search and add keys into the Main activity fragment adapter. What I want is when we search and add the key to the adapter, the app should take the user directly to the third activity, which is populated by the the main activity adapter, taking away the need for user to goto main activity, tap the recently added key.

Is there a function to grab the most recently added item in an adapter? I am currently using the following code in the key search activity, it kicks in immediately after the key is imported:

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ViewKeyActivity.class);
viewIntent.setData(
                    KeychainContract.KeyRings.buildGenericKeyRingUri(KeyListFragment.mAdapter.getMasterKeyId(KeyListFragment.mAdapter.getCount() - 1)));
            startActivity(viewIntent);
```

but the issue is I am getting a null pointer error, since the adapter only seems to respond the above code when the user navigates back to the main activity.
I have already tried `KeyListFragment.mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` 
Also its worth mentioned that the intent used here was used in the main activity on the item click listener of the listview:

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ViewKeyActivity.class);


        viewIntent.setData(
            KeyRings.buildGenericKeyRingUri(mAdapter.getMasterKeyId(position)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        //mManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        //mManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mManager);
```

Comment: can you elaborate more on this please?